# ChildIOException: error in snake make after running flye

Tags: snakemake

So I have an issue when I run other programs after I ran flye in my snakemake pipeline. This is because the output from flye is a directory. My rules are as followd:

```
samples, = glob_wildcards("data/samples/{sample}.fastq")

rule all:
    input:
    [f"assembled/" for sample in samples],
    [f"nanopolish/draft.fa" for sample in samples],
    [f"nanopolish/reads.sorted.bam" for sample in samples],
    [f"nanopolish/reads.indexed.sorted.bam" for sample in samples]


rule fly:
    input:
        "unzipped/read.fastq"
    output:
        directory("assembled/")
    conda:
        "envs/flye.yaml"
    shell:
        "flye --nano-corr {input} --genome-size 5m --out-dir {output}"


rule bwa:
    input:
        "assembled/assembly.fasta"
    output:
        "nanopolish/draft.fa"
    conda:
        "nanopolish.yaml"
    shell:
        "bwa index {input} {output}"

rule nanopolish:
    input:
        "nanopolish/draft.fa",
        "zipped/zipped.gz"
    output:
        "nanopolish/reads.sorted.bam"
    conda:
        "nanopolish.yaml"
    shell:
        "bwa mem -x ont2d -t 8 {input} | samtools sort -o {output}"
```

there are a few steps before this but they work just fine. when I run this it gives the following error:

```
ChildIOException:
File/directory is a child to another output:
/home/fronglesquad/snakemake_poging_1/assembled
/home/fronglesquad/snakemake_poging_1/assembled/assembly.fasta
```

I have googled the error. All I could find there that its because snakemake doesnt work well with output directorys. But this tool needs a output directory to work. Does anyone know how to bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I think) The problem lies somewhere else in your code.

You have defined two rules, the first that outputs directory `assembled`, the second that outputs `assembled/assembly.fasta`. Since the output of the second rule is always at least the directory `assembled`, Snakemake complains. You can solve it by using the directory as input:

```
rule second:
    input:
        "assembled"
    output:
        ...
    shell:
        cat {input}/assembly.fasta > {output}
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped